# Inequality involving sine and cosine

Tags: inequalities, trigonometric-sums

I am trying to prove that given $A,B,C,D,E,F \in \big]0,\frac{\pi}{2}\big]$ fixed and $A+C \geq E$ and the following equation holds for $\mu = 1$:

$$\sin(\mu A)\cos(\mu B) + \sin(\mu C)\cos(\mu D) - \sin(\mu E)\cos(\mu F) \geq 0$$
then it holds for all $\mu\in [0,1]$.

Note obviously if $B \leq F$ and $D \leq F$ the statement is trivial to prove.

I checked numerically and it holds, however whatever I tried to prove it did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: But it is not well defined on the described domain: imagine that $E$ is almost 0.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Ah, that is true. I forgot to add another condition.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I updated the question.

Comment: I also tried to simplify as: $$\sin(\mu A)\cos(\mu B) + \sin(\mu C)\cos(\mu D) - \sin(\mu \min(A+C, \frac{\pi}{2}))\cos(\mu \arccos(\frac{\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(C)\cos(D)}{\sin(\min(A+C, \frac{\pi}{2}))}))$$, but showing that this is smaller than the above and also showing it is still larger than zero does not look like it is easier.

Comment: may I ask, does this question come from certain geometry problem?

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes it comes from a problem in a metric space I am trying to solve. Thats why I can add extra conditions like $B+D≥E$. Those come from the triangle ineq in the metric space, given that the points have the correct configuration. I tired to state the problem in a more general for so it can be useful as a standalone lemma too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid it is false. Take $F=0$, $A=C$, $E=2A$, $\mu=1/2$. Then we are given $\cos B+\cos D=2\cos A$ and should prove $\cos B/2+\cos D/2\geqslant 2\cos A/2$. But if $\cos B=x$, then $\cos B/2=\sqrt{(1+x)/2}$, this function is concave, thus inverse inequality $\cos B/2+\cos D/2\leqslant 2\cos A/2$ holds.

Comment: Please note that I specified $A,B,\ldots,F \in ]0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. In particular $F=0$ is not possible.

Comment: Yes, but it is certainly not important: take very small $F$ if you do not like zero, and accordingly slightly change $B,D$.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your example. I see how you derive the first equality, however I believe it should be $\geq$ there. The last inequality does not contradict the required one as there could be equality...

Comment: It is strict if $B\ne D$.

Comment: ok, that looks correct. I guess I will require another condition, $B+D \geq E$...

Comment: I am happy to give you the bounty, however I like to keep the question open with the additional condition as I try to find a way to get this inequality working. Not sure how this is usually done here.

Comment: @LorenoHeer It's generally not a good idea to keep changing the question as responses come in. This usually winds up being frustrating to the community.

Comment: @Todd Trimble I will try not to change it anymore. However it is also inconvenient to ask a new question with only slightly changed conditions.

Comment: @LorenoHeer I understand; I'm stating a general guideline, but you are free to continue as you see best.

Comment: I think in your answer you meant, $\cos(B/2) = \sqrt{(1+x)/2}$. I understand the argument. I will definitely need to add $B+D \geq E$ as requirement. Hopefully that is the only one.